# how can I change the default TCP service proxy_timeout in Kubernetes maintained nginx ingress?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I've tried to change the default proxy_timeout(600s) to 3600s for tcp services in k8s maintained nginx-ingress.But its not working.

I have exec the nginx-controller pods and got the following in nginx.conf.

```
# TCP services

server {
        preread_by_lua_block {
                ngx.var.proxy_upstream_name="tcp-test-test-db-test-lb-dev-7687";
        }

        listen                  7687;

        proxy_timeout           600s;
        proxy_pass              upstream_balancer;

}
```

i have used following configmap and found not working.I'm getting still 600s timeout.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxyTimeout: 3600s
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-stream-timeout: 3600s
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: 3600s
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: 3600s
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: 3600s
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy_timeout: 3600s
data:
   7687: "test-test-db/test-lb-dev:7687"
   8687: "test-test-db/test-lb-test:8687"
```

Anyone please help me to short this issue out.

Answer (score 1):

When using these annotations you have to set them to number (integer) values. For example:

```
 ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-stream-timeout: "3600"
```

instead of:

```
ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-stream-timeout: 3600s
```

If you need more details regarding the timeout options than please check the [official docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/).

Comment: thanks for the answer
then i think   ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-stream-timeout: "3600s" as it takes string as per document you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Annotations does not work in tcp-services for updating `proxy_timeout` parameter in nginx.
You need to update the configmap `ingress-nginx-controller` and add the `proxy-stream-timeout: "3600s"` under `data`. (A sample below)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
data:
  proxy-connect-timeout: "10"
  proxy-read-timeout: "120"
  proxy-send-timeout: "120"
  proxy-stream-timeout: "3600s"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not correct. Not in the tcp-cm and not as annotation.
Add as Data --> proxy-stream-timeout: 3600
to the other configmap.